# past notification appear in present

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I'm trying to make an app that notification reminding something in specific date and time but i having the problem is when the code running the past notification also appears..
for example; yesterday is 7 march 2014 in specific time i set a notification but today 8 march 2014 in specific time i set deferent notification in this case when i run the code yesterday notification also appears so i need stop yesterday notification please someone help to fix this

```
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

[df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"];

NSDate *myDate = [df dateFromString:@"2014-03-08 16:35"];
NSDate *myDate1 = [df dateFromString:@"2014-03-08 16:36"];
NSDate *myDate2 = [df dateFromString:@"2014-03-08 16:39"];
NSDate *myDate3 = [df dateFromString:@"2014-03-08 16:40"];

UILocalNotification* n1 = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];

n1.fireDate = myDate;








n1.alertBody = @"one";



UILocalNotification* n2 = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];



n2.fireDate=myDate1;
n2.alertBody = @"two";

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification: n1];

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification: n2];



UILocalNotification* n3 = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];

n3.fireDate = myDate2;









n3.alertBody = @"one";



UILocalNotification* n4 = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];


n4.fireDate=myDate3;
n4.alertBody = @"two";

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification: n3];

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification: n4];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use

```
  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];
```

and then reschedule new ones.